# Materialize View creation not supported from DLT Pipeline

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-unity-catalog

I have a very basic scenario where I am using my custom catalog and want materialize view to get created from DLT table at the end of pipeline. The SQL used as below for the same.

[image]

where "loom_data_transform" is a Streaming table. But pipeline fails at the last stage where materialize view is tried to create from "loom_data_transform" with following error message.

[image]

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '__materialization_mat_loom_data_report_1' was read as a stream (i.e. using `readStream` or `STREAM(...)`), but '__materialization_mat_loom_data_report_1' is not a streaming table. Either add the STREAMING keyword to the CREATE clause or read the input as a table rather than a stream.
```

Could someone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I able to resolve it but the fix is really surprising.
When Materialize view need to be created from stream table as base, the syntax should be

```
live.loom_data_transform
```

in place of

```
STREAM(live.loom_data_transform)
```